# Where Rashi uses a Russian word in Nach?

Tags: words, tanach, rashi, language, sources-mekorot

I heard that Rashi uses a Russian word where he deals with the building of the Beis Hamikdash by King Shlomo. I also heard that he uses a Polish word.

Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: wow talk about self critical i love your name

Comment: @simchashatorah I doubt [it was meant to be taken literally](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/what-is-the-source-that-parshas-parah-is-from-the-torah#comment26516_14409).

Comment: @simchashatorah: besides, it could be meant in the sense that Rashi explains to Lev. 20:1: עם שבגינו נבראת הארץ.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14587/5

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In his commentary to [I Kings 6:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%95_%D7%96):

> ומקבות" - דלוט"א בלשון רוסיא"

Although it seems quite likely that this is a later interpolation; it doesn't appear in early prints of Rashi.

In several places, though, Rashi refers to לשון כנען, which was a popular term at the time for the Slavic languages (based on the equation of "Slav" with "slave" and the association of the latter with Canaan). These include Deut. 3:9 (שניר הוא שלג... ובלשון כנען), Shabbos 20b in Hagahos HaBach (פסולתא דזיפתא... עיטרן שקורין דוהינו בלשון כנען), Avodah Zarah 28b (חיפושתא... ובלשון כנען קרוקי"ם) and 51b (דסחיפא לה משכילתא ארישיה... כלי ארוך ובלשון כנען אקדון). Some of these might indeed be Polish, although I don't know.

Comment: +1. "Snow" in Slavic languages is things like _shneg_. In (modern) Polish it's _śnieg_ (pronounced roughly "shnek"); in (modern) Russian _снег_ ("snek"); in (modern) Ukrainian _сніг_ ("snih" I think). I don't see a language that has anything closer to _s'nir_ than the Salvic languages, though a number of other Indo-European languages (esp. Germanic languages) are about as close to _s'nir_ as the Slavic.

Comment: @msh210, indeed. Rashi there gives German (where the word is *schnee*) and Slavic as similar to *s'nir*. One possibility is that he might have been referring specifically to Czech, in which the word is *snih*, just like in Ukrainian (and geographically it's a lot closer to France). Silbermann has an interesting discussion of this in the endnotes to his edition of the Chumash.

Comment: Could you please send me a scan of Silbermann's discussion about this? Goolge Books only has a snippet view of it, see http://books.google.co.il/books?id=pLwSAQAAIAAJ&q=inauthor:%22Abraham+Maurice+Silbermann%22+slavic&dq=inauthor:%22Abraham+Maurice+Silbermann%22+slavic&hl=en&sa=X&ei=X-4dUdWuEOWR4AS4zYHwCw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA Thanks!!