# Where does Rashi say "Complaint" in his commentary on the Torah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, pentateuch-chumash

When I was in 4th grade, my rebbi taught us a Rashi in which he explains a Pasuk by simply saying "Complaint" (קומפליינט or some similar transliteration), meaning the voice in the Pasuk was dissatisfied with something. Where is this?

(Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14580/where-rashi-uses-a-russian-word-in-nach))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be thinking of [Rashi to Ex. 15:24](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%98%D7%95_%D7%9B%D7%93), where he explains the reflexive form וילונו ("they complained," or more literally, "they were becomplained") by comparing it to French *decomplaisant se*, where *se* is similarly reflexive.

(He also uses קומפליינ"ט *complaint* as the translation of מתנודד in Jer. 31:17, and קומפלויינ"ט *comploint* (?) for ומרודי in Lam. 3:19.)

[Otzar Laazei Rashi on Tanach](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48057&pgnum=102) gives also the following variations (the Latinizations are his):

קונפליינדר"א (conpleindre) - Job 2:11 (not found in standard editions)

קונפליינ"ט (conpleint) - Jer. 1:6, 4:31

קונפליינט"א (conpleinte) - Job 42:11

as well as, [in the volume on Gemara](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48058&pgnum=189), the following:

קומפליינ"ץ (compleinz) - Rosh Hashanah 34a (standard editions have קומפלייני"א)

קונפליינ"ט (conpleint) - Bava Basra 9a

So maybe indeed your teacher showed you the one in Rosh Hashanah?

Comment: I agree: Seth J was more likely learning _B'shalach_ than _Yirmiya_ or _Echa_ in fourth grade.