# Chazzon Ish and Parshas Parah being D'Oraisa

Tags: sources-mekorot, four-parshiot

I heard today that the Chazzon Ish says that the reason Parshas Parah is m'doraisa ([See here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/what-is-the-source-that-parshas-parah-is-from-the-torah)) is because of the pasuk:

> והזהרתם את בני ישראל מטמאותם
>
> "And you shall separate the children of Israel from their uncleanness"

That through the reading of Parshas Parah b'tzibbur Klal Yisrael will know how to stay away from tumah. The fact that reading it b'tzibbur will be the best way to spread the news (a car with a microphone can't be sent around.)

This person had claimed to have seen this inside from the Chazzon Ish (in one of his seforim or perhaps brought down in his name.) Does anyone have a source for this?

Comment: That passuk is used for separation close to vestos and it happens to be a machlokes if it is a doraisa ir drabbanan.

Comment: sam is right. If this has been extended beyond Niddah, why not also read about lots of other types of Tumah?

Comment: @DoubleAA I realized sam's point as soon as this person told me this over. However he's a Talmud Chacham and remembered seeing it inside just doesn't remember "where". So that's why I'm bringing this here today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sefer Shaarei Yemei HaPurim - page 32](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47884&st=&pgnum=44&hilite=) mentions this in the name of the Steipler Zatzal.